# Kentico - Displaying child items through transformations

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, content-management-system, kentico

I've a situation where there is a conditional case where the editor can pick the layout of the child items.

[image]

As can be seen from the image above, **NewsItems** is of type *NewsContainer* which provides the option for the layout of the child items of type *NewItem*. If the picked layout is of type, *two items per row* , the child items should be displayed vertically otherwise horizontally. The image below shows the transformation structure, where I need to access the properties of child news items.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

PS: Kentico version: 10

**UPDATES based on comments**
As per Roman's comment, I tried this, but still nothing appears in the output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Applying individual transformations directly to the Transformation field of the repeater, produces the output, but it does not work, when using the macro.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused by your description. The transformation would be applied for those News1-4 pages right? So you need to access the layout property of the parent page, not child page, correct? If so, I would recommend to switch to Text/XML transformation type and use this macro:

```
{%Documents[Documents[NodeAliasPath].Parent.NodeAliasPath].GetValue("LayoutField")%}
```

and just FYI from your screenshot the NewsItems page doesn't seem to be a container page type -> it's more probably content only page type that can't list standard pages.

Comment: I'll try this and come back, and yes the page types are like you said.

Comment: This does not seem to return any value for me.

Comment: Is the NodeAliasPath part of your Columns configuration (or is the Columns property empty)? Do you have the Text/XML transformation? I have tested it and it works just fine.

Comment: Yes, I tested it with Text/XML transformation, and it returned blank output. How/Where to check for **Columns Configuration** ?

Comment: It's your Repeater's configuration. I can see it's empty in your updated post, but the macro does work - I've doublechecked it - please share entire configuration of your repeater -> there is a link for exporting at the bottom of that web part.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement two separate transformations and use their code names as values in the Layout drop down. Now you should place some listing web part (repeater, uni viewer, etc.) on the 'container' page and enter `{%Layout%}` macro into web part transformation field.

Comment: I'll try this and come back.

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't seem to work. Please see the updated question with images.

Comment: No, but the output is totally blank.

Comment: I'm sure this approach should work, however the most correct solution in your case would be implementation of a widget based on listing web part you're currently using. All properties should be pre-populated with values and not visible to a content editor, but one - transformation.

Comment: So there are two possible reason for a blank output: either path/where condition is no correct so web part does not select any documents to show or there is something wrong with transformations. For the second one you can put some static text into transformation and see if it appears on the page.

Comment: yes tried that already ... and it works if the transformation is specified directly using a name directly instead of a macro.

Comment: Then widget is a way to go.

Comment: as you can tell, I'm just getting started with kentico. Can you tell me how to access the child items/nodes from inside an ascx transformation ? That's all i need for now.

Comment: ASCX transformation is similar to a user control, so you can write any server side code in it. Also you could implement transformation method (https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/adding-custom-methods-to-transformations)

Comment: I meant, what API method to use to access the children  ??? Kentico docs are either non-intuitive or incomplete or not very clear since I could not find it anywhere.

Comment: Use Document Query. Here are some samples: http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/kentico-8-technology-documentquery-api

Comment: will try in a whike and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to conditionally populate transformation field using Macros. Something like this.

```
{% CurrentDocument.ApplyTransformation( ([YOURCONDITION] ? "[TRANSFORMATION_A]" : "[TRANFORMATION_B]") ) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Roman's method is clean, however if you purely want to do it in one transformation, this is what you would do.

```
<%# IfCompare(Eval("Layout"), "horizontal", "The content if it's NOT horizontal", "the content if it IS horizontal") %>
```

The IfCompare is an odd ball that it's 'false' is first and 'true' is second (hate that).

You can put all your logic in the "" then, OR you can make life a little easier if you're okay with some duplicate code and just display both and hide whichever is applicable

```
<div class="horizontalLayout <%# IfCompare(Eval("Layout"), "horizontal", "hidden", "") %>">
  Horizontal Here
</div>
<div class="verticalLayout <%# IfCompare(Eval("Layout"), "horizontal", "", "hidden") %>">
  Vertical Layout here
</div>
```

See [Transformation method references](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/reference-transformation-methods)

Comment: yes this is exactly something that I tried to do, but don't know how to access the child items from the transformation in the NewsContainer type.